# Issue installing python 3.7.0 on win7

Tags: python

I am on windows 7 integral version, and can't install python 3.7.0 and I already updated it with SP1.

This is the log file of the failed setup:

```
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i001: Burn v3.11.1.2318, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\{220AB437-83C6-48A3-9C01-2AFBBD04E308}\.cr\python-3.7.0-amd64.exe
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'ShortVersion' to value '3.7'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'ShortVersionNoDot' to value '37'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'WinVer' to value '3.7'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'WinVerNoDot' to value '37'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallAllUsers' to value '0'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallLauncherAllUsers' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDir' to value ''
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultAllUsersTargetDir' to value '[ProgramFiles64Folder]Python[WinVerNoDot]'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetPlatform' to value 'x64'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultJustForMeTargetDir' to value '[LocalAppDataFolder]Programs\Python\Python[WinVerNoDot]'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'OptionalFeaturesRegistryKey' to value 'Software\Python\PythonCore\[WinVer]\InstalledFeatures'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDirRegistryKey' to value 'Software\Python\PythonCore\[WinVer]\InstallPath'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultCustomTargetDir' to value ''
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'CustomInstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value '[InstallLauncherAllUsersState]'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDirState' to value 'enabled'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'CustomBrowseButtonState' to value 'enabled'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_core' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_exe' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_dev' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_lib' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_test' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_doc' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_tools' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_tcltk' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_pip' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_launcher' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'Include_launcherState' to value 'enabled'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_symbols' to value '0'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_debug' to value '0'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'LauncherOnly' to value '0'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DetectedLauncher' to value '0'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DetectedOldLauncher' to value '0'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'AssociateFiles' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Shortcuts' to value '1'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'PrependPath' to value '0'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'CompileAll' to value '0'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SimpleInstall' to value '0'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Initializing string variable 'SimpleInstallDescription' to value ''
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=D:\software\python-3.7.0-amd64.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=172 -burn.filehandle.self=180'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'D:\software\python-3.7.0-amd64.exe'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'D:\software\'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Python 3.7.0 (64-bit)_20180830082919.log'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Python 3.7.0 (64-bit)'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Python Software Foundation'
[0BAC:07F4][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Setting numeric variable 'CRTInstalled' to value 0
[0BAC:0E24][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Did not find D:\software\unattend.xml
[0BAC:0E24][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Setting string variable 'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'
[0BAC:0E24][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Setting string variable 'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'
[0BAC:0E24][2018-08-30T08:29:19]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '3.7.150.0'
[0BAC:0E24][2018-08-30T08:29:19]e000: Detected Windows 7 RTM
[0BAC:0E24][2018-08-30T08:29:19]e000: Service Pack 1 is required to continue installation
```

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with your Service Pack 1 installation, try to reinstall it with these instructions;

- [Go to the Windows 7 Service Pack 1 download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842) on the Microsoft website.
- Select Install Instructions to see which packages are available for download, and make note of the one that you need.
- Select the appropriate language from the drop-down list, and then select Download.
- Select the packages you need to install, select Next, and then follow the instructions to install SP1. Your PC might restart a few times during the installation.
- After SP1 is installed, sign in to your PC. You might see a notification indicating whether the update was successful. If you disabled your antivirus software before the installation, make sure you turn it back on.

More details: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15090/windows-7-install-service-pack-1-sp1

After this, try to install Python 3.7 normally again.

Comment: @FlyingTeller But something probably went wrong with the installation since Windows is complaining about the service pack. Can't hurt to try to install it with the correct instructions.

Comment: i had to uninstall all update and install the sp1 update and that's work now